# AssetNotPrecompiledError when using html5-rails gem in production env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I've got [html5-rails](https://github.com/sporkd/html5-rails/) and [compass-html5](https://github.com/sporkd/compass-html5/) working in devlopment on rails 3.1 but when I run my app in production mode and try to visit my homepage, I get the following:

```
Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths::AssetNotPrecompiledError in Home#index

polyfills.js isn't precompiled
```

The thing is that localhost:8080:/assets/polyfills.js does display. I suspect there is a problem with my methods:

**Steps to reproduce:**

**1** Create new rails app with home controller, index action and set up a root route and delete *public/index.html* and *views/layouts/application.html.erb*

**2** Add following to Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'unicorn'
group :assets do
  gem 'compass', "~> 0.12.alpha.0"
  gem 'sass-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'compass-html5', :git => 'https://github.com/sporkd/compass-html5.git'
  gem 'html5-rails', :git => "https://github.com/sporkd/html5-rails.git"
end
```

**3** Run `rails g html5:install` to create */config/compass.rb* file

**4** Create */config/initializers/sass.rb* containing following code:

```
Rails.configuration.sass.tap do |config|
  config.load_paths << "#{Gem.loaded_specs['compass'].full_gem_path}/frameworks/compass/stylesheets"
end
```

**5** Run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

**6** Run `unicorn -E production` (or `rails s -e production` if you're on webrick) and visit root url

**7** Observe bug

The correctly minified *respond-md5.min.js* and *modernizr-md5.min.js* are present in **/public/assets**. The compiled js code does appear when I visit *localhost:8080/assets/modernizr.min.js*. The server error is thrown when I try to visit my homepage.

I suspect there is an error in my method. I have asked the very same question [here](https://github.com/sporkd/html5-rails/issues/2) on github.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to fix this by adding polyfills.js to application.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( polyfills.js )
```

Answer (score 0):

i just got the same error, and the issue was that my file was missing...